# RaisePropertyChanged of dependent property is called only once

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm programming a WPF application with VS 2015.
In my window i have per example a TextBox and a ToggleButton for switching between FontWeights.Bold and FontWeights.Normal.
In my ViewModel i have two properties. One for the IsChecked-property of the ToggleButton and the other for the FontWeight of the TextBox.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets if the button setFontBold is checked.
/// </summary>
private bool? setFontBoldIsChecked = false;
public bool? SetFontBoldIsChecked
{
    get { return setFontBoldIsChecked; }
    set
    {
        setFontBoldIsChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SetFontBoldIsChecked");
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextFontWeight");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the fontweight depending on SetFontBoldIsChecked.
/// </summary>
public FontWeight TextFontWeight
{
    get { return (setFontBoldIsChecked == true) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal; }
}
```

The FontWeight-property of the TextBox is bound like that:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" FontWeight="{Binding TextFontWeight}"/>
```

And the IsChecked-property of the ToggleButton is bound to SetFontBoldIsChecked:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="setFontBold" IsChecked="{Binding SetFontBoldIsChecked}"/>
```

When i start the application and click the ToggleButton, so IsEnabled is true, the text appears bold.
But if i try this one more time, RaisePropertyChanged("TextFontWeight") doesn't call the Getter of TextFontWeight.

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Comment: That works for me. There must be something you haven't shown us.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the following:
I have a MainWindow on which i drag&drop controls - like Label - from a toolbox.
After drop the property-setting-window with the ToggleButton and the TextBox (for preview) is opened.
After i adjusted the properties and saw the result in the TextBox, i confirm it and the window is not closed but hidden with the Hide-command.
Before hiding the window, i reset all properties in my ViewModel to default values.
This means SetFontBoldIsChecked=false.
When i drop the next control, the Setting-window appears again and Raise doesn't fire the Getter of TextFontWeight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague i have found it out!
In the XAML all attributes have to be set:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textForTextProperty" FontWeight="{Binding TextFontWeight, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And the properties in the viewmodel have to be changed a little bit:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets if the button setFontBold is checked.
/// </summary>
private bool? setFontBoldIsChecked = false;
public bool? SetFontBoldIsChecked
{
    get { return setFontBoldIsChecked; }
    set
    {
        setFontBoldIsChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SetFontBoldIsChecked");
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextFontWeight");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the fontweight depending on SetFontBoldIsChecked.
/// </summary>
private FontWeight textFontWeight;
public FontWeight TextFontWeight
{
    //get { return textFontWeight; }
    get
    {
        textFontWeight = (SetFontBoldIsChecked == true) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
        return textFontWeight;
    }
    set
    {
        textFontWeight = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextFontWeight");
    }
}
```

Now it works.